# How to correctly use guard clause in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard, clause

What is the correct way to use the guard clause in this sample?

```
def require_admin
  unless current_user && current_user.role == 'admin'
    flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
    redirect_to root_path
  end        
end
```

I don't know where to put flash message when trying to rewrite using these https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-conditionals conventions

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `return` statement here. Essentially, there is no need for the method to continue *if* those conditions are met, so you can bail out early.

```
def require_admin
  return if current_user&.role == 'admin'

  flash[:error] = 'You are not an admin'
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: This is older, but I still thought I'd add a small suggestion to that return clause. Since we have the safe navigation operator in ruby, we can refactor that guard clause to `return if current_user&.role == 'admin'` which is even more succinct.