# Using guard clause on code block

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have this method:

```
  def self.get_image(product_id)
    self.initialize

    product_id=product_id.to_s
    if @image_db.key?(product_id)
      if Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at'] > @refresh_period
        puts Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at']
        self.cache_image(product_id)
      else
        return @image_db[product_id][':uri']
      end
    else
      self.cache_image(product_id)
    end
  end
```

and I am getting rubocop errors to use a guard clause instead of an `if`-`else` statement. What would be the best way to do this?

I was contemplating this code:

```
  def self.get_image(product_id)
    self.initialize

    product_id=product_id.to_s
    return if @image_db.key?(product_id)
    return if Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at'] > @refresh_period
    puts Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at']
    self.cache_image(product_id)
  end
```

but this line would never be called:

```
return @image_db[product_id][':uri']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and I am getting rubocop errors to use a guard clause instead of an
>   if-else statement... **what would be the best way to do this**?

First of all read carefully few articles on what guard clause is.

Here is your method refactored to use guard clauses:

```
def self.get_image(product_id)
  initialize

  product_id = product_id.to_s

  return cache_image(product_id)       unless @image_db.key?(product_id)
  return @image_db[product_id][':uri'] unless Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at'] > @refresh_period
  puts Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at']
  cache_image(product_id)
end
```

I would probably move some parts of method out to simplify it a bit:

```
def self.get_image(product_id)
  initialize
  product_id = product_id.to_s
  return cache_image(product_id)       unless @image_db.key?(product_id)
  return @image_db[product_id][':uri'] unless cached_at_gttn_refresh_period?(product_id)
  puts Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at']
  cache_image(product_id)
end

private

def cached_at_gttn_refresh_period?(product_id)
  Time.now.to_i - @image_db[product_id][':cached_at'] > @refresh_period
end
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey for this, was enlightening. 

For anybody else who needs help with guard clauses, along with Andrey's answer, I found these links that helped me out a lot: 

http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2009/02/16/using-guard-clauses-in-your-ruby-code/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943125/how-to-correctly-use-guard-clause-in-ruby

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/GuardClause